# The least value of the length

Tags: geometry

Let $ABC$ be right triangle in $B$ such that $\mid BC\mid=1$ and $\mid BA\mid=\sqrt{3}$.Let $E$ and $D$ be two points on $AC$ and $AB$.How to find the least value of the length $DE$ in order to make the area of triangle $ADE$ to be half the area of triangle $ABC$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I had a more straightforward way to find the solution:

M is midpoint of AC, AH=AB,N is midpoint of HM,circle NH, get G, $ AG=\sqrt{\dfrac{AB*AC}{2}} $. circle AG, cross AB at D, cross AC at E. DE is the shortest line which cut triangle ABC into equal areas.

in case $AB<AD$, ie, $c < \dfrac{b}{2}$,then BM will be the solution.

Proof:

let AC=b,AB=c,AD=x,AE=y, then $ \dfrac{xySinA}{2}=\dfrac{1}{2}*\dfrac{bcSinA}{2} $, ie. $ xy=\dfrac{bc}{2}$ ,be care $ x\leq c ,y \leq b$

$ \ ED^2=x^2+y^2-2xyCosA=x^2+(\dfrac{bc}{2x})^2-bcCosA$

since $bcCosA$ is constant, we can let

$ f(x)=x^2+(\dfrac{bc}{2x})^2$ 
 clearly $ f(x) \geq  bc$  ,when and only when $x=\dfrac{bc}{2x}$, ie. $ x_{f_{min}} =\sqrt{\dfrac{bc}{2}}$. if $c < \dfrac{b}{2}$, then $x_{f_{min}} >c$,

$f'(x）=2x-(\dfrac{bc}{2x^2})^2*2x$, when $c<\dfrac{b}{2}, x\leq c <\sqrt{\dfrac{bc}{2}}$,then $\dfrac{bc}{2x^2}>1$, that is$ f'(x)<0$, it means, then $x$ is max, $f(x）$ is min. the max of $x=c$, so $ y=\dfrac{b}{2}$, which mean DE=BM

Comment: your case is very simple, you put all number in, will get $ED= \sqrt{2\sqrt{3}-3} $

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** I would pick a coordinate system, with $B$ as the origin and $BA$ and $BC$ as axes, then if $D=(\sqrt3-d,0)$ and $E=(x,y)$, what is the area of $\Delta ADE$, and knowing that $E\in AC$, how can you express $x$ by $y$? Then write up $DE^2=(x-(\sqrt3-d))^2+y^2$.

Comment: What is the final answer ?

Answer (score 0):

I give a compass and straight  method to find the shortest one. see picture

[image]

You may take time to proof the method then it is very easy to find the final answer.

the key is to convert triangle into a Isosceles and then find the shortest one will be easier. it is not so easy to proof in Isosceles.